# Pulling * from multiple, identically structured tables

Tags: mysql

Each of these identically structured tables holds the model of the vehicle and the associated price. I need to create a single array(my result) of all these model/prices to use.

`MySQL.Async.fetchAll('SELECT * FROM vehicles', {}, function(result)`

Works while:

`MySQL.Async.fetchAll('SELECT * FROM commercial, motorcycles, muscleandclassics, supercars, truckandsuvs, vehicles', {}, function(result)`

does not. I’m unable to retrieve an error from the second failed query but I’ve stopped retrieving the result so I’m wondering what I need to do to get my result to retrieve the content from those tables to add to the result.

Comment: You'll need to `JOIN` the tables together.

Comment: What you have attempted is the equivalent of a massive "cross join"; you need to look into `UNION`s. Also, `SELECT *` is generally discouraged outside of test/"dev" queries; there are just too many long term maintainability issues to use it for "production" queries.

Comment: Side note: If your tables are identical in every way but name, you probably should consider just having one table with an additional field indicating "type".

Comment: Yes. The elephant in the room

Answer (score 0):

You could `union all` a bunch of queries on those tables:

```sql
SELECT * FROM commercial
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM motorcycles
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM muscleandclassics
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM supercars
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM truckandsuvs
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM vehicles
```